# No such field found: field java.lang.String sinput error while running my jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

Getting `No such field found: field java.lang.String sinput` error while running my Jenkinsfile.

I have developed a Jenkinsfile that would take a user input and further would run a command on remote machine taking the user input as a variable

```
stages {
    stage("Interactive_Input") {
        steps {
            script {
                def apiinput
                def userInput = input(
                        id: 'userInput', message: 'This is my project',
                        parameters: [
                                string(defaultValue: 'None',
                                        description: 'Enter the name of the service',
                                        name: 'sinput'),
                                
                        ])
                // Save to variables. Default to empty string if not found.
                apiinput = userInput.sinput?:''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution:

```js
apiinput = userInput ? : ''
```

---

Explanation:

You are accessing your variable `sinput` wrongly. Your `id: 'userInput'` does stand directly for the variable of the user input. You try to access a variable that does not exist when you call `apiinput = userInput.sinput ? : ''`.

Quoting from Source3:

> If just one parameter is listed, its value will become the value of
> the input step.
> If multiple parameters are listed, the return value will be a map
> keyed by the parameter names. If parameters are not requested, the
> step returns nothing if approved.

You have 1 parameters so it becomes the value of the input step. No map is created.

[Cloudbees 1](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/204986450-Pipeline-How-to-manage-user-inputs) | [Cloudbees 2](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/226554067-Pipeline-How-to-add-an-input-step-with-timeout-that-continues-if-timeout-is-reached-using-a-default-value) | [Pipeline Input Step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, could you please suggest what changes do i need to make in my code.

Answer (score 6):

well ... I had such an issue and in my case it was the way I was using variables
When I did like `$VARIABLE` it wasn't working and I had an error like the one described here.
However when I did `${VARIABLE}` -> it has all worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was trying to access `length` as an attribute instead of `length()` as a method. Basically missing parenthesis.